# Oracle pl/sql reference(return?) cursor/declared cursor

Tags: sql, oracle, cursor

Is there a way to do something like this?  Output a cursor's fetched data into a refcursor without stuffing it into a table first?

```
create or replace procedure someprocedure
(
rc1 in out adv_refcur_pkg.rc)  -- this is defined below
as

v_class_year varchar(10);

cursor c1
is
select distinct e.pref_class_year
from entity e
where e.pref_class_year between i_start_class and i_end_class;

begin
open c1;
loop
fetch c1 into v_class_year;
EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;

end loop;
close c1;

open rc1 for select v_class_year from dual;
end;
```

here is the refcursor's declaration

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE ADVANCE.adv_refcur_pkg
AS
TYPE RC IS REF CURSOR;
END adv_refcur_pkg;
```

Comment: Simply open the `rc1` cursor for query used in the `c1` cursor definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According with this example, yes, it's possible:

https://forums.oracle.com/thread/696634

Answer (score 0):

Why go to the trouble of doing that when you can simply pass the cursor itself?

```
create or replace procedure someprocedure
(
rc1 in out adv_refcur_pkg.rc)  -- this is defined below
as
begin
open rc1 for
   select distinct e.pref_class_year
     from entity e
    where e.pref_class_year between i_start_class and i_end_class;
end;
```

When you call "someprocedure", you have an open cursor you can then fetch from:

```
BEGIN
...
  someprocedure(TheCursor);
  LOOP
    fetch TheCursor into v_class_year;
    exit when TheCursor%NOTFOUND;
    ...
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE TheCursor;
...
END;
```